# How to join columns from two files using awk/sed command?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting, columns

I have two files File-1 and File-2 with data in columns. I want to create another file and copy the data of the first column of File-2 corresponding to the data to file-1 in row wise as given below.

## File-1

```
A  P
B  Q
C  R
```

## File-2

```
5.4  9.0
7.4  11.5
9.4  15.7
```

## Output

```
A=5.4, B=7.4, C=9.4
```

I want my output in a row form like above only for first column data. 
I appreciate your help!! 
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ paste file1 file2 | awk '{printf "%s%s=%s", sep, $1, $3; sep=", "} END{print ""}'
A=5.4, B=7.4, C=9.4
```

Comment: wow great!!!
thanks @Ed Morton

Answer (score 3):

Note that a "join" (mentioned in the question title) is a specific operation where one data set is used to extract data from another data set (a relational join operation).  This may be done with the `join` utility (or with a short `awk` command).

What you want to do is a data extraction and a merge. This is well explained by you in the question text.

Assuming you have the `bash` shell, the contents of the first column of each file can be extracted using `cut`, and then merged with `=` as a delimiter using `paste`:

```
$ paste -d '=' <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 File-1) <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 File-2)
A=5.4
B=7.4
C=9.4
```

Each `<(...)` (process substitution) will be replaced with the name of a temporary file from where the output of the `cut` command inside the substitution will be available for `paste` to read.

You can then merge this into a single comma-delimited line like so:

```
$ paste -d '=' <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 File-1) <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 File-2) | paste -d ',' -s -
A=5.4,B=7.4,C=9.4
```

If you require spaces after each comma, `sed` may be used:

```
$ paste -d '=' <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 File-1) <(cut -d ' ' -f 1 File-2) | paste -d ',' -s - | sed 's/,/, /g'
A=5.4, B=7.4, C=9.4
```

Note that I have assumed that the empty lines in the question is not actually part of the data files. You may want to pre-process the data with `sed '/^[[:blank:]]*$/d'`, which would delete any lines that are empty or that only contains spaces and/or tabs.

See also the manual for `cut` and `paste` (`man cut` and `man paste`).